# flask read json file

Tags: python, flask

I am new in flask. I have a **parsed.json** file. i want to get parsed.json file data from url with get methods. I have try solution post on stackoverflow but my problem is not solved.Hope for solution

this is json data in parsed.json file

```
{
    "OfficeServicesID": "1",
    "OfficeID": "1",
    "Service": "eVoting Booth",
    "officeID": "1.0",
    "Office": "Elton Mckenzie",
    "Suburb": "Hurstville",
    "Phone Number": "+61 2 3556 3485",
    "Email": "hurstville@myoffice.gov.au",
    "Lat": "-33.975869",
    "Lon": "151.08893899999998"
},
{
    "OfficeServicesID": "2",
    "OfficeID": "1",
    "Service": "Justice of the Peace",
    "officeID": "2.0",
    "Office": "Kennith Graves",
    "Suburb": "Sydney",
    "Phone Number": "+61 2 3753 2374",
    "Email": "sydney@myoffice.gov.au",
    "Lat": "-33.867139",
    "Lon": "151.207114"
},
{
    "OfficeServicesID": "3",
    "OfficeID": "2",
    "Service": "Library",
    "officeID": "3.0",
    "Office": "Myrna Duke",
    "Suburb": "Auburn",
    "Phone Number": "+61 7 3375 3892",
    "Email": "auburn@myoffice.gov.au",
    "Lat": "-33.849321999999994",
    "Lon": "151.033421"
},
```

**my code**

```
table = []
with open('parsed.json', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        table.append(json.loads(line))


tasks = table



app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/getservices/', methods=['GET'])
def getservices():
    return jsonify(tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

when goto url http://127.0.0.1:5000/getservices/
i want result **like this**

```
[


    {
    "OfficeServicesID": "1",
    "OfficeID": "1",
    "Service": "eVoting Booth",
    "officeID": "1.0",
    "Office": "Elton Mckenzie",
    "Suburb": "Hurstville",
    "Phone Number": "+61 2 3556 3485",
    "Email": "hurstville@myoffice.gov.au",
    "Lat": "-33.975869",
    "Lon": "151.08893899999998"
    },
    {
    "OfficeServicesID": "2",
    "OfficeID": "1",
    "Service": "Justice of the Peace",
    "officeID": "2.0",
    "Office": "Kennith Graves",
    "Suburb": "Sydney",
    "Phone Number": "+61 2 3753 2374",
    "Email": "sydney@myoffice.gov.au",
    "Lat": "-33.867139",
    "Lon": "151.207114"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you're trying to read is actually invalid. It displays a list of objects, but is not enclosed in square brackets `[]`. As Laurent suggested, try fixing your JSON with square brackets `[{...}, {...}, {...}]` first, then parse it.

To parse, get rid of the `for` and assign the table directly to `json.loads`, like this:

```
with open('parsed.json', 'r') as f:
    table = json.loads(f.read())
```

Again, don't forget to fix your JSON first.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your "parsed json" with a pair of brackets "[...]"

```py
import json

table = []

with open('parsed.json', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()

# remove trailing comma:
content = content.rstrip(",")

# wrap with brackets:
content = "[" + content + "]"

# pase the json list
table = json.loads(content)
```

Simple and efficient…

Comment: error  File "C:\Users\BuildChange\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 877 column 1 (char 17046)                I am getting this